# SSH access parent host folder

Tags: linux, macos, ssh

After connecting to a remote server (A) through `ssh` is it possible to access host's folder/files?

This server A has access to another server (B) which I can't access from my computer. I need to run some commands on B using some config files on my computer.

Comment: The remote computer won't have any way to access data on your local computer just because you have an SSH session open. You could SFTP the files to `A`, then SSH to `A` and SFTP them again to `B` then SSH to `B` and do your work.

Comment: If you are going to do this often between local and `B` then you could set up an NFS mount between `A` and `B` to share, then SFTP (or SCP or RSYNC over SSH) to that NFS mount on `A` and then will be accessible by B via the mount. That would be one less hop. If the NFS mount is ON `A` then you could make it so it's mountable by both local and `B` and then just move the files locally to the mount and they will be accessible by `B` too. There are a few options here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying the files from my computer to A using `scp` and run the commands there.